# Should we have a new Buddhism stack favicon?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Can we have a nice favicon for our stack instead of BU, like the Christianity or Hinduism stack... I propose the dhamma wheel as a favicon.

Comment: [This comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/how-can-we-change-the-favicon-of-se-site-in-beta#comment850643_259901) suggests they may want to see an upvoted suggestion before they act, so I made this a 'featured' topic ... if you agree with the suggestion, please upvote this question.

Comment: Yes I meant others: see [Voting is different on meta](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta), "*Unlike* normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. **On posts tagged [meta-tag:feature-request], voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change** rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: @ChrisW does this not receive further enthusiasm? maybe people not see the meta. Can we make this as stack question?

Comment: It is a meta-topic, i.e. a question about the site; I try to keep to the rules about what and where to post, sort of regardless of my personal preferences. Let's let this here another few weeks: maybe it will become a bit more visible on the main site, when the other "Featured on Meta" topics age off the top of the list.

Comment: I have upvoted. Let's hope others do so too.

Comment: (visitor comment): Just for food for possible good thought: it is one thing to take such what owned by others and another to sacrifice own.

Aside of this, Sadhu & mudita if the merirs have made toward the Tripple gems.

Comment: Meaning "should WE have..." could be terrible unskilful at first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some designs for evaluation and comments by the moderators and the community. They are based on "Unicode Symbol: ☸ (U+2638: Wheel Of Dharma)".

I post them here as square PNG images for ICO conversion using [this website](https://www.favicon-generator.org/) for example, or GIMP.

Here's the SE dialog box versions (outside the dialog box, it's transparent):

[image: Saffron dialog version] for Buddhism.SE

[image: Black dialog version] for Buddhism.Meta.SE

Here's how they may look like next to the titles when you click on the top right Stack Exchange menu bar icon:

[image: Buddhism.SE titles dialog version]

---

Here are the rounded box versions (outside the rounded box, it's transparent):

[image: Saffron Dhammachakra rounded box small] for Buddhism.SE

[image: Black Dhammachakra rounded box small] for Buddhism.Meta.SE

Here's how they may look like next to the titles when you click on the top right Stack Exchange menu bar icon:

[image: Buddhism.SE titles rounded box]

---

Here are the standalone versions (the rest transparent) - I like this one the best:

[image: Standalone saffron] for Buddhism.SE

[image: Standalone black] for Buddhism.Meta.SE

Here's how they may look like next to the titles when you click on the top right Stack Exchange menu bar icon:

[image: Buddhism.SE titles standalone]

Comment: That looks  incredie!!!

Comment: Now altogether, there are 3 editions.

Comment: I see it has been implemented.

Answer (score 7):

[How can we change the favicon of SE site in Beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259897/139866) suggests that yes, this may be possible!

I think it's a good idea -- so I upvoted your question, and I invite other people to upvote it too.

A favicon is a 32x32 icon. Here's the icon from Hinduism.SE:

[image]

That's not too small for a recognizable Dharmachakra, for example:

[image]
 [image]

I made the above image, by:

1. Copying "Unicode Symbol: ☸ (U+2638: Wheel Of Dharma)" from [Dharmachakra -- Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmachakra#Symbol)
2. Pasting it (using a suitable font size like 22 or 26, and a default font family like Consolas).

Or perhaps (unless there's a reason to stay with blue) an appropriate color would be orange (or 'saffron') e.g. as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254375/allowing-css-customization-of-beta-sites#comment830691_254375) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(colour)#Hinduism_and_Buddhism).

Let's see whether SE developers agree to implement it. The above-linked answer says,

> The correct way to do this is to create a meta post (on Hinduism Meta, not the main meta) with the tag [feature-request](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). Stack Exchange employees monitor that tag across all meta sites in the network. You should get an answer from them in due course, though it may take [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514) before you get an answer, and then another arbitrary amount of time before anything is actually done.

---

P.S.: [Different Stack Exchange sites have the same logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130133/139866) says it's important (for usability) that sites have dissimilar favicons.

The current "Bu" icon is similar to "B", "BH", "BI", "BC", and "BG" icons used by [other sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name).

Comment: Keep hope for saffron! [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) is a Stack Exchange beta site with a non-blue favicon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes please. I like the dhamma wheel as a favicon. "Unicode Symbol: ☸ (U+2638: Wheel Of Dharma) Simple and reproducible. (Y)

Comment: Please upvote the question and ChrisW's answer